# Why between my logins I get also Facebook?

Tags: support, login, openid, facebook

When I look at my logins, the dialog box shows that I am using two of them: Stack Exchange and Facebook. I am just using Stack Exchange. Why Facebook is also shown as login?

> [image: screenshot]

I have tried removing the Facebook login using the "remove" link, logging out from https://stackexchange.com/users/79630/kiamlaluno, and logging in back. Still, I get Facebook listed as one of the logins.

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: Stupid question: you didn't "accidentally" log in via Facebook?

Comment: No, I have always used Stack Exchange since the last time I had problems with OpenID servers. As you can see, all the times I login with Stack Exchange, it shows as if I used Facebook too, when I only use Stack Exchange.

Comment: Weird. (Almost as weird as the downvote) I have no clue if those somehow can become connected. What happens if you removed it and try again?

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't change anything. Facebook is shown as one of the logins, even if I am only using Stack Exchange.

Comment: Facebook sticks. Once you logged in one time, it's there forever or at least that's what happened to me and I was too lazy to report it properly. I'm pretty sure you did choose to log in via Facebook one time, maybe by mistake and you don't even remember. After that, the "used ... ago" is always synchronized no matter what you do or how you're logged in.

Comment: By the way, are you auto logged in to Facebook? If so, try logging out then remove it from your logins and see what happens.

Comment: I'm assuming you don't mind your email addresses being displayed here?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd The email I use to log in on facebook.com is not even that. I tried logging out from Facebook, removed that login from my logins, logging out, and logging in back. Facebook is still shown between my logins.